# Sorting Descending order: Java Map

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

What I want to do is sort a map by value. I went over many questions that are available on the stackoverflow site and found out following solution that does what I want but missing a small thing.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top): Sorting Map

But the issue I am running into is that by default this is sorted by ascending order by value. I want to order it by descending order:

So what I did was I created a class that implements a comparator

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator {
    Map map;
    public MyComparator(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Integer) map.get(o2)).compareTo((Integer) map.get(o1));
    }
}
```

And then I pass my map to the treemap,

```
MyComparator comp = new MyComparator(myMap);
Map<String, Integer> newMap = new TreeMap(comp);
newMap.putAll(myMap);
```

This seems like bad approach because I feel this is inefficient. Is there a way to change the solution in the link to do ordering on descending order by default.

Comment: You'd be surprised by what is and is not inefficient. You should run some tests... make a map of 50,000 random Integers and sort it this way, see how long it actually takes. (And do that 100 times or more, so you get a good average.) Try not to go with what you "feel" is inefficient.

Comment: If you actually read the comments in the linked answer, you'll discover that the technique you're using is actually a _really bad idea_.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2581754/869736 is the only answer to that question that really works in general.

Answer (score 136):

You should use `new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());`.

```
Map<String, Integer> newMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
newMap.putAll(myMap);
```

or to reverse an existing comparator like the value-comparator `Collections.reverseOrder(comparator)`. It works like your approach swapping the two objects before invoking `compare`/`compareTo`.

Comment: the following is not working,  please find correction, String "aaaaaaaabcdefgggghijkllllllllllmmmnoppponono"            TreeMap<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Character, Integer> (Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (Character charItem: s.toCharArray()) {
            map.put(charItem, map.getOrDefault(charItem, 0) + 1);
        }

Comment: See image here, https://ibb.co/wSv62Jz

Comment: @mattsmith5 don’t let me guess what you expected or why you think the output is wrong. `totalcount` is zero because you never increment it and the output is truncated at the bottom. Besides that, it’s exactly what to expect.

Answer (score 7):

```
    TreeMap<Long,String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Long,String>();

    NavigableMap <Long, String> nmap = treeMap.descendingMap();

    Set<Long, String> set = nmap.entrySet();

    Iterator<Long, String> iterator = set.iterator();
```

now u can iterate over iterator and extract the value using  iterator.hasNext() and iterator.next() methods ......

Answer (score 4):

This will work :

```
      TreeMap<Integer, Integer> reverseInteger=new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2>o1?1:o2==o1?0:-1;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply invert the return value of your compare method by adding a minus sign at the beginning:

```
return -((Integer) map.get(o2)).compareTo((Integer) map.get(o1));
```

Comment: Very bad idea. If `compareTo` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE` your code breaks. Swapping `o1` and `o2` *as already done in this code* does the job better.

Answer (score 0):

To change the solution in the link to sort by descending order, just reverse the condition:

```
...
// Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
public int compare(String a, String b) {
    if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
        return 1; // For ascending, return -1;
    } else {
        return -1; // For ascending, return 1;
    } // returning 0 would merge keys
}
...
```